# Set EndDate to GetDate() when a record is deleted in the ODS

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, ssis

I have the following data flow :

[image]

where I am merging between :

ODS Left Join :

```
SELECT bn.EmployeeId
      ,bn.CountryId
      ,bn.OdsCreateDate FROM ODS.BridgeNationality bn
WHERE bn.EmployeeId=15366
```

DWH Right Join

```
SELECT bn.EmployeeId
      ,bn.CountryId
      ,bn.InsertDate
      ,bn.BI_EndDate FROM DWH_Amaris.dwh.BridgeNationality bn
WHERE bn.EmployeeId=15366
```

Merge Join Type : Full Outer 
[image]

In the Conditional Split Transformation, in the Delete condition I put :

```
!ISNULL(EmployeeIdDWH) && ISNULL(CountryIdODS)
```

And in the OLE DB Command after the Delete Branch :

I am updating the EndDate of the record which doesn't exist anymore in the ODS :

```
UPDATE [DWH].[BridgeNationality]
   SET [BI_EndDate] = GETDATE()
 WHERE [EmployeeId] = ?
AND CountryId=?
```

Like for example I have  in the DWH :

```
EmployeeId CoutryId  InsertedDate EndDate 
15366      US        2020-03-18   9999-12-31         
15366      FR        2020-03-18   9999-12-31
```

and in the ODS :

```
EmployeeId CoutryId   
15366      US
```

We can see that the FR nationality has been removed in the ODS so I need to update the EndDate of the record having FR in the DWH to the `GETDATE()` like below :

```
    EmployeeId CoutryId  InsertedDate EndDate 
    15366      US        2020-03-18   9999-12-31         
    15366      FR        2020-03-18   2020-03-19
```

The problem is everytime I execute the package it keeps always updating the record having FR nationality in the DWH however it should be done once.

Answer (score 1):

You have to add that the record is having EndDate="9999-12-31" in your condition like below :

```
!ISNULL(EmployeeIdDWH) && ISNULL(CountryIdODS) && BI_EndDate == (DT_DATE)"9999-12-31"
```

Otherwise, the update will be infinte like in your case.